# Call webservice which has HTML type of data by using Jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I am new to jquery.

I have created web service which returns HTML data. 
Eg. It returns  `<div>TestData</div>`.

I want to call this web service by using jquery.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have HTML like this:

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

then you can load your web service's HTML content into it like this:

```
$('#result').load('/webservice/service.php');
```